# Integration and extraction of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, nested-function

I'm not explaining it well and I think it's a long explanation leading up to the key question, sorry.

There is order[x] consisting of randomly selected number {a,b} elements.

```
order[x]={{{a1,b1},{a1′,b1′},{a1′′,b1′′}},{{a2,b2},{a2′,b2′},{a2′′,a2′′}},…}
```

I give list of real number as an examples.
(For example,[x]range is {x,3})

```
order[x]={{{5,1},{1,2},{4,2}},{{5,1},{2,1},{3,3}},{{1,1},{2,2},{5,1}}}
```

So, order[x] consists of the following.

```
order[1]={{5,1},{1,2},{4,2}}
order[2]={{5,1},{2,1},{3,3}}
order[3]={{1,1},{2,2},{5,1}}
```

Next, I change {a,b} to the form {{a,b},c}.  C is the number of occurrences of {a,b}.

```
accumulatedCounts = 
  MapThread[
     KeyValueMap[List]@*KeyTake]@{Accumulate[
      KeyUnion[Counts /@ #, 0 &]], #} &;
inputlist = order[x];
reOrder[x] = accumulatedCounts@inputlist
```

As the result,

```
reOrder[x]={{{{5,1},1},{{1,2},1},{{4,2},1}},{{{5,1},2},{{2,1},1},{{3,3},1}},{{{1,1},1},{{2,2},1},{{5,1},3}}}
```

Next is main issue.

When I put 1 in reOrder[x], {{{5,1},1},{{1,2},1},{{4,2},1}} is not output.
If I write `reOrder = accumulatedCounts@inputlist`, reOrder〚1〛is output {{{5,1},1},{{1,2},1},{{4,2},1}}

However I don't hope this form.
I want the output to be in the form [x], not〚x〛.
So,

```
reOrder[1]={{{5,1},1},{{1,2},1},{{4,2},1}}
reOrder[2]={{{5,1},2},{{2,1},1},{{3,3},1}}
reOrder[3]={{{1,1},1},{{2,2},1},{{5,1},3}}
```

What would you suggest I do?

Comment: I think you may be mixing up lists and arrays. `temp = accumulatedCounts@inputlist; Table[reOrder[x] = temp[[x]], {x, Length[temp]}]`. But why not just use lists?

Comment: Thank you for your help!I have no choice but to use it in the course of my issue.